# how to create NSCollectionView using swift for os x

Tags: macos, swift, nscollectionview

I am not able to find out any tutorials for os x. Can someone help me with how to create NSCollectionView using swift for os x.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?? Please post what you've attempted.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [video tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LtGt-B94No) on the topic by Vea Software.

Apple provides a Sample Code called [Exhibition](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/Exhibition/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016178-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) ([video session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=221)). The specific Swift file showing the code required to interact with an NSCollectionView is [ImageListController.swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/Exhibition/Listings/Exhibition_ImageListController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016178-Exhibition_ImageListController_swift-DontLinkElementID_10).

If you want to learn more about the new NSCollectionView, there's a whole WWDC session and the [video is available from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=225), but the presenter uses Objective-C, not Swift.

Another Sample Code from Apple is [CocoaSlideCollection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/CocoaSlideCollection) which shows a lot more of the capabilities of the new NSCollectionView but is also in Objective-C, not Swift.

You should know that NSCollectionView was significantly improved in OS X 10.11 El Cap, which was announced in Jun 2015. The apps you develop using the new and improved NSCollectionView will not work on earlier versions of OS X.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for, thank you for providing this!

Comment: I wrote a very simple example in Swift: https://github.com/klaas/CollectionViewElCapitan

Comment: Thanks to all of you. You saved my day !

Comment: What about self sizing ?:( I can't implement it

Comment: i want image on cell so what should apply code in NScollectionview in swift 3.0 like same as a your example in for label array type in my code array in image name how do that plz help i m stuck here